# Can you change a SQL port at the database level rather than the instance level?

Tags: sql, port

Can you change a SQL port at the database level rather than the instance level?  Trying to force an application using SQL at the database level. General question only thanks.

Comment: The server is the "software" handling the databases. You can access the server through a port. One server can have multiple databases. Your question is like asking if you can start a specific instance of MS WORD for a specific Word file. You can't. You can run multiple sql server instances in parallel, listening to different ports. But it's a hassle to manage.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and "SQL" knows nothing about "ports" or "instances"). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the port cannot be changed at a database level, assuming you are using SQL Server. It can be changed at only the server/instance level.

Know that the instance is serving connections. Once you connect to the server, then you choose the database and then the objects under that database. The port of entry is the server and that's where the port is defined.

In case you haven't run into this doc, check it out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks and yes I am using SQL server.  Did the research beforehand but just wanted to be sure that I did not miss anything.